# Auto resizing of images in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap by twitter and I am using the carousel. I am wanting the image to have a fixed height of 500px and width greater than 100% allowing the image to always fill the container

```
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: = 100%;
  height:  500px;
}
```

I want the image to always be larger than the container and always be proportional.

Comment: It would behoove you to show all of your Markup, not just the CSS.

Comment: You want the width to be greater than **100%** of **what** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the CSS `background-size` property.

Make an image stretch to use 100% of the `width` while maintain aspect-ratio...

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Make an image stretch to use 100% of the `height` while maintain aspect-ratio...

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```